# JavaScript. An Odd Assignment Sentence

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var test=(a=1,[b=2]["sort"])();
```

This code works in Firefox resulting test=window (window object),

Is it valid JavaScript code? (I failed to find it in JavaScript references)

Comment: I get can't convert undefined to object in Fx 8 http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/fnGL7/

Comment: Chrome also gives: `TypeError: Array.prototype.sort called on null or undefined`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's "valid" but looks completely pathological to me. From the name of the `var`, I'd guess someone came up with this as a feature test at some point, but failed to add a comment explaining why.

So here's what it's doing. First, the two assignments will resolve to the assigned value, so we can replace them (they do assign variables, which is a side effect, but that doesn't affect the evaluation of this expression):

```
var test=(1, [2]["sort"])();
```

["sort"] is just .sort:

```
var test=(1, [2].sort)();
```

The comma operator will return the last value in the brackets, so we can lose that 1:

```
var test=([2].sort)();
```

So now the bracketed part is creating an array with the number 2 in it, and finding the `sort` method of that array. It then calls that method, but because of the first set of brackets it calls it without a specified context.

In non-strict mode, a function called with no context gets `window` as its `this`.

So it tries to sort `window` and returns the result, which is `window`, as you saw.

In strict mode, which the JS consoles in Firebug and Chrome are, functions called without context get `undefined` as their `this`, which means this example throws an error, as mplungjan noted above. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode

Comment: *A bracketed expression will return the last value in the brackets, so we can lose that 1*: That's not 100% correct. The *comma operator* will evaluate all expressions and return the result of the last one. It would be the same if there were no brackets.

Comment: _It then calls that method, but because of the first set of brackets it calls it without context._ According to section 10.2 of ECMA 262 (3rd edition),the first set of brackets calls `sort` method in global object instead of "without context", If my understanding is right.

Comment: Good point, I'll rephrase that to "without a specified context".

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that code to give an error.

The comma basically evaluates the expression on the left, `a=1` and then the expression on the right `[b=2]["sort"]` and returns the result of the expression on the right.

`a=1` sets `a` to 1, creating `a` as a global if it's not in the current scope.

`[b=2]` sets `b` to 2, creating `b` as a global if it's not in the current scope, and also creates a one-element array with the value 2.

`[b=2]["sort"]` returns the array `.sort` method (it does not call the method).

So the result of the expression in parentheses is the array `.sort` method which is then executed by the final `()`, and the result would be assigned to `test` except that it doesn't work because by then it is not actually called on an array.

The final assignment is the equivalent of this: `var test = ([2].sort)();`.

Comment: In non-strict mode it will call it on `window`, which does not cause an error.

Comment: Thanks for that @N3dst4 - I tried it in FF and Chrome and got an error in both. Didn't think about strict versus non-strict mode.